# Can't call string because it's initialized by the user?

Tags: java, string, input

I'm making a sort of text adventure game in java and basically I have an int named WeaponChoice. I have the user input a number between 1 and 3.

I then have an if statement which basically goes like

```
if(WeaponChoice == 1){
    Weapon = "Sword"
}
```

The problem is that when way later on I try to print a line with the Weapon variable (as I don't want to make an if statement for each weapon) it claims the variable hasn't been initialized.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
    System.out.println("You enter the front entrance, with your " + Weapon + " at ready."); 
and the error message is "the local variable Weapon may not have been initialized."

RESOLVED
Resolved by adding a default value in an else statement.

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting?  What is the code you are running that generates the error?

Comment: System.out.println("You enter the front entrance, with your " + Weapon + " at ready.");
and the error message is "the local variable Weapon may not have been initialized."

Comment: Please don't add content as comments; edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: Take a look at your program.  If `WeaponChoice` isn't `1`, what value will `Weapon` have?

Comment: And 4 = ?, and 42 = ?, and 1000000 = ?  You can't assume your user will give you good input.

Comment: Where is Weapon defined ? It should be defaulted to something. Perhaps when declaring the String you can assign a value or set it to at least blank. String Weapon = " "; or something like String Weapon = "No Weapon Selected";

Comment: If its over 3 it just shows an error message but the No Weapon Selected thing makes sense, i'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should involve declaring WeaponChoice as an Array rather than a string

```
String[] WeaponChoice = new String[20];
```

then

```
private void populateStringArray()
{
    WeaponChoice[0] = "Sword";
    WeaponChoice[1] = "Pepperoni";
    WeaponChoice[2] = "Anvil";
}
```

Comment: I initially tried this and it makes more sense but how would the user input that? right now I have it as input.nextInt(); for the WeaponChoice int

Comment: Essentially the same way you would do it now.  The user would have a choice from say, a dropdown that sends a value of 1,2,3, etc...  Once their selection is made, you have the integer for their choice.  When you call it back later, you just display WeaponChoice[selected].

Answer (score 0):

Changing my response now that I understand the actual error.

The Java compiler will give you this error if there is at least one route of execution through your code that will result in `Weapon` having never been initialized.  Common causes for this are if/else if statements with no final else that gives a default value, or switch statements without a default case to insure that a value is assigned.

For example:

```
String Weapon;
if( choice == 1 ) {
  Weapon = "Sword";
} 
else
if( choice == 2 ) {
  Weapon = "Bow";
}
System.out.println(Weapon);
```

As far as the compiler is concerned, it is possible that your code can execute and choice will be neither 1 nor 2, and so Weapon won't be initialized (hence the word "may" in your error message).  The fix is to do one of the following:

1. Assign a default value, e.g. `String Weapon = "Sword";`
2. Add an else at the end that assigns a default value, e.g.

   `else {
       Weapon = "No Weapon";
   }`